# Dimensional Modelling: OLAP Operation on Data Cube

Tags: olap-cube, dimensional-modeling, data-cube

Assume that we have a data cube as follows:

```
DairyFarms = { <Name, Time , Product> , <Sales> , <Sum> }
Name = {Farm1, Farm2, Farm3, Farm4}
Time = {Jan, Feb, Mar , ..... , Dec}
Product = {Milk, Butter, Cheese, Yogurt}
```

Suppose I want to retrieve the sales of Cheese across all the farms during January. Which of the following two queries is correct?

```
i) DairyFarms[Name*][Jan][Cheese]
ii) DairyFarms[][Jan][Cheese]
```

Do both of them mean the same or is there any difference between them w.r.t. correctness and/or efficiency?

Comment: Is this an exa, question? I'm not familiar with the syntax you have posted.

Comment: What kind of software and/or architecture does this refer to? What is 'w.r.t'?

Comment: w.r.t. = "with respect to". Of course when writing a question the poster should avoid confusing acronyms. It's like writing plz instead of please. If you can't be bothered writing the whole word you clearly don't mean it!